# After adding a destructor, i have error before program had invoked it

Tags: c++, destructor

(Sorry for my English, I'm Ukrainian)I am doing a program that realized a "Stack of Numbers" (console application). I'll want add the destructor that will be cleaned dynamic memory, after deleting stac. When i do my stac without destructor - [all right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdUYf.png), if i am adding destructor - i have [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JjBA.png). Destructor is invoked when application is ended but i have error when program is invoking first function. Without destructor i haven't this error. It is my source code, where destructor is commented out.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<ctime>
using namespace std;

struct Oneof
{
int num;
Oneof* next;
};

class Stac
{
private:
Oneof * first;
public:
/*~Stac();*/
Stac(); 
Stac(Stac &n);  
void New(int n);                 //Adding new element
int Remove();                    //Reading last element and removing it
int SetLast();                   //Reading last element without removing        
void Read();                     //Reading all stac
friend bool Eq(Stac a, Stac b);  //Equive two another stacs 
};

Stac::Stac(){first=NULL;}

Stac::Stac(Stac &n){first=n.first;}

/*Stac::~Stac()
{
    while(first!=NULL)
    {
        Oneof *temp=first;
        first=first->next;
        delete temp;
    }   
}
*/

void Stac::New(int n)                   //Adding new element
{
Oneof* temp=new Oneof;
temp->num=n;
temp->next=first;
first=temp;
}

int  Stac::Remove()                     //Reading last element and removing it
{
int a=first->num;
Oneof *temp=first;
first=first->next;
delete temp;
return a;
}

int  Stac::SetLast()                    //Reading last element without removing
{
return first->num;
}

void Stac::Read()                       //Reading all stac
{
Oneof* temp=NULL;
Oneof* save=NULL;
save=first;
while(first!=NULL)
{
    temp=first;
    cout<<temp->num<<" ";
    first=temp->next;
}
first=save;
}

bool Eq(Stac a, Stac b)                 //Equive two another stacs
{
Oneof* tempa=a.first;
Oneof* tempb=b.first;
while(tempa!=NULL && tempb!=NULL)
{
    if(tempa->num==tempb->num)
    {
        tempa=tempa->next;
        tempb=tempb->next;
    }
    else return false;
}
if(tempa==NULL && tempb==NULL)return true;
else return false;
}

int main()
{
Stac a;
srand(time(0));
for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        a.New(rand()%100);
    }
Stac b(a);

cout<<"Chek equive...\n";
bool equ=Eq(a,b);
if(equ==0)cout<<"First!=Second\n";
else cout<<"First==Second\n";

cout<<"\nReading without removing first number of fisrt stac...\n";
int n=a.SetLast();
cout<<n<<endl;

cout<<"\nReading first Stac...\n";
b.Read();

cout<<"\n\nReading second Stac...\n";
a.Read();

cout<<"\n\nAdding new number and reading first Stac...\n";
b.New(rand());
b.Read();

cout<<"\n\nRemoving number and reading second Stac...\n";
int last=a.Remove();
cout<<last<<endl;
a.Read();

cout<<"\n\nChek equive...\n";
bool equ1=Eq(a,b);
if(equ1==0)cout<<"First!=Second\n\n";
else cout<<"First==Second\n\n";

system("pause");
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Your copy-constructor barely copy anything, it's no different than the default copy-constructor which does *shallow* copying (like you do).

Answer (score 2):

Your function `Eq` takes two `Stac` objects *by value*

```
bool Eq(Stac a, Stac b)
```

Therefore `a` and `b` will be *function local copies* of your inputs. Therefore after the function ends, they will fall out of scope and their destructors will be called. To avoid making local copies, pass the objects by `const&`

```
bool Eq(Stac const& a, Stac const& b)
```

Comment: Either that, or implement a proper copy-constructor (which is a better solution in the long run, IMHO).

Comment: You can change your function signature to the second method I mentioned (passing by `const&`). Also as @JoachimPileborg mentioned your copy constructor is not written correctly, it only copies the first item, it should make a deep copy of all the items.

Comment: Thank for all, i understanded. Because my cope-conctructor is wrong, when i delete elements from first Stac, i delete this elements and from second Stac too. And, because of this, destructor can deleted elements only for one Stac and, when it try to delete element from another - i see error.

Comment: This just postpones the inevitable. It isn't fixing the root cause of the problem.